# How to generate random number with a kind of required probability?

Tags: algorithm, random

In my game a user should be able to specify a probability when one or another random scene should be shown up with two integers `A_x` and `B_x`. Say, when `A_x = 3`, `B_x = 6` a scene `B` should be shown in general 2 times frequently than scene `A`.

Are there any read-to-use formulas? Could you please point me out on them?

The first imagined idea of mine is smth. like saving the previously generated scene id and count it accordingly to the probability criterias `A_x` and `B_x`; but it looks silly.

Comment: What language? What platform?

Comment: possible duplicate of [c++, how randomly with given probabilities choose numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8642135/c-how-randomly-with-given-probabilities-choose-numbers)

Comment: @Oded: C++, but I am looking for a general idea not a ready solution.

Comment: Possibly, but a functional algorithm would be as useful, would it?

Answer (score 3):

With just two alternatives, you can work out the probability of A as A_x / (A_x + B_x) = 1/3. If you have a random number generator returning numbers uniformly distributed between 0 and 1 with a call such as rr.nextDouble() then something like the following should work.

```
if (rr.nextDouble() <= probA)
{
   show A
}
else
{
  show B
}
```

This generates A if the random number generator generates something <= probA, which should happen with probability probA.

Comment: where the formula `A_x / (A_x + B_x) = 1/3` was taken/derived from?

Comment: It seemed obvious. Probabilities should sum to one. If you divide A_x and B_x by some value you can change their sum, while keeping the modified values in the same ratio as the originals. A_x + B_x is what you divide by to make the results sum to one.