# Semi-random numbers generation in C++

Tags: c++, random

Suppose I have a set of numbers x = {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3}. Is there a way for me to use rand() to print out random numbers from this list so that the proportion of the generated numbers over time actually would be the original proportion of the numbers in the set? In other words, so that the proportion of zeros would be about 0.5, ones would be 0.125, twos would be 0.25, and threes would be 0.125.

Comment: Yes it is possible. Now go out and do it! :)

Comment: You can use [std::discrete_distribution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20254952/1708801).

Comment: Put them in a `std::vector` and and use `std::shuffle` on it. Then use them in the shuffled order.

Comment: What you want is a distribution, go and take a look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random

Comment: Any decent pseudo random number generator will do that given large enough N.  Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by specifying the frequencies:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    mt19937_64 engine;

    discrete_distribution<int> numbers{4, 1, 2, 1};

    cout << numbers(engine) << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

quick approach:

```
int values[8] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3 };
int randomIndex = rand() % 8; // NOTE: feel free to replace with & 0x7
int randomValue = values[randomIndex];
```

NOTE: to provide uniform distribution number of values should be power of 2 (2,4,8,16,etc). If you need another number, you can use following:

```
int rand_range(int maxValue)
{
    int mask = 0;
    int tmp = maxValue;
    int r;

    while (tmp > 0)
    {
        mask = (mask << 1) | 1;
        tmp= (tmp>> 1);
    }

    r = rand() & mask;
    while (r > maxValue)
        r = rand() & mask;

    return r;
}

int values[XXXX] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, ... };
int randomIndex = rand_range(XXXX-1); // NOTE: -1 as maxValue is inclusive
int randomValue = values[randomIndex];
```

Comment: This has the advantage over discrete_distribution that you are not limited to 0..n

Comment: Result may be biased however. Depending on the required accuracy this could be a problem.

Comment: @MatthiasB do you mean usage of `%`?

Comment: Yes. As far as I know rand in combination with modulo will not generate a completely uniformly distributed range of numbers.

Comment: @MatthiasB for arbitrary divisor - you're right, for 8 - it will provide uniform distribution

Comment: @Lashane if I were to call `rand()` in a loop, am I correct in remembering that the value produced by `rand()` would be the same in every pass in the loop in the current instance of the program? And then `rand() % 8` would also be the same?

Comment: @UnworthyToast you're wrong, rand will return different values each time